# Does N/H=K/H under some terms mean N=K?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G.$ Now let $H$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ containing $K.$ Given $N/K=H/K$ can I show $N=H$ necessarily? Is there a way?

Comment: The assumption is that they are the same group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H/K = N/K$, then $N=H$ by the correspondence theorem: there is a bijection between the subgroups of $G$ containing $K$ and the subgroups of $G/K$

Comment: That's just what I was thinking a second before I had this black out, thanks!

Comment: Oh I am sorry. 
I thought I already did so...